# when to use factory and when to use service - counter approach is suggested in a book

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm reading [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783983566) about angular's services. When summarizing about when to use `service` and `factory` methods of provider the author states the following:

> The service method should be used if you define your services as a class and  need to invoke the definition's constructor function. Use
>   the factory method if you define your service as an object instance
>   and do not need to invoke a constructor.

I'm wondering whether this is a typo or I have been misusing them. I've always used the `factory` method to get constructors and `service` when I needed instances.

**EDIT**:

For example, I have a validator service and each controller in the app should have it's own instance. I define it as a class:

```
function ValidatorService() {
    this.addErrorRule = function (event, rule) {};
    this.validate = function (values) {}
}
```

Now, I would define it in the angular system using `factory` method like this:

```
angular.module("validation").factory('ValidatorService', function () {
    return ValidatorService;
});
```

Whenever a controller requires `ValidatorService` it will be provided with the constructor from which a service can be instantiated.

But according to the quote:

> The service method should be used if you define your services as a
>   class and  need to invoke the definition's constructor function.

I should have done like this:

```
angular.module("validation").service('ValidatorService', ValidatorService);
```

But in this case angular will instantiate one instance of the service which will be shared among all controllers.

Comment: Show example of what you mean. What the author is saying is technically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Angular `service` recipe the function passed is invoked like a constructor function and that is what the author is referring to when he says

> The service method should be used if you define your services as a
>   class and need to invoke the definition's constructor function.

Whereas for a `factory`, the framework executes the recipe function and the return value is cached and returned every time you inject the service.

Normally factories are used to return objects but for your `factory` recipe implementation the return value is a constructor function and hence your interpretation is different from what the author explains.

Comment: thanks! _Whereas for a factory, ...the return value is cached and returned every time you inject the service._ - but with the  `.service()` the returned value is also cached, right?

Comment: Right, since the service is a constructor function, the framework create the service instance by calling constructor function and caches it.

Comment: So is my approach with returning `factory` functions (classes) using `.factory()` method is not logical? What should I use to return `classes` to allow multiple instances? `.value()` maybe?

Comment: What you have done is just fine. We too use similar approach to share our model with the app. See this post https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/angular-model-objects-with-javascript-classes-2e6a067c73bc. For other cases we us the factory just to return a service object

Comment: Got you, thanks! Actually I might consider using `value()` for models. I've just found this suggestion in the book I'm reading: _Another good use for the value method is to define model objects that will be used
by your components._

Answer (score 1):

accepted
From the AngularJS mailing list I got an amazing thread that explains service vs factory vs provider and their injection usage. Compiling the answers:

**Services**

Syntax: module.service( 'serviceName', function ); 
Result: When declaring serviceName as an injectable argument you will be provided with an instance of the function. In other words new FunctionYouPassedToService().

**Factories**

Syntax: module.factory( 'factoryName', function ); 
Result: When declaring factoryName as an injectable argument you will be provided with the value that is returned by invoking the function reference passed to module.factory.

**Providers**

Syntax: module.provider( 'providerName', function ); 
Result: When declaring providerName as an injectable argument you will be provided with ProviderFunction().$get(). The constructor function is instantiated before the $get method is called - ProviderFunction is the function reference passed to module.provider.

Providers have the advantage that they can be configured during the module configuration phase.

Comment: Yeah, that's what's mentioned in docs and that's how I've been using them. However, the question is why the author states otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a different approach to answer your question. I believe the code can be improved to fit into a `service` and achieve the recommendation you quoted of:

> The service method should be used if you define your services as a class and need to invoke the definition's constructor function.

Rather than creating instances of a `ValidatorService` that requires rules be added to the instance to run validation on, you should try a more functional approach.

```js
function ValidatorService() {
  this.validate = function(rules, values) {
    //Loop over rules/values
    return Math.random() * 10 //used only to show that validates are independent;
  };
}

angular
  .module('test', [])
  .service('validator', ValidatorService)
  .factory('validatorFac', function () {
    return function (rules, values) {
        return Math.random() * 10; //used only to show that validates are independent;
    };
  })
  .controller('TestController', ['$scope', 'validator', function($scope, validator) {
    $scope.isValid = validator.validate([],[])
  }])
  .controller('AnotherTestController', ['$scope', 'validator', function($scope, validator) {
    $scope.isValid = validator.validate([],[])
  }])
  .controller('TestFacController', ['$scope', 'validatorFac', function($scope, validatorFac) {
    $scope.isValid = validatorFac([],[])
  }])
  .controller('AnotherTestFacController', ['$scope', 'validatorFac', function($scope, validatorFac) {
    $scope.isValid = validatorFac([],[])
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <p>Is Valid: {{ isValid }}</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="AnotherTestController">
    <p>Is Valid: {{ isValid }}</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="TestFacController">
    <p>Is Valid: {{ isValid }}</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="AnotherTestFacController">
    <p>Is Valid: {{ isValid }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the service and factory approaches are essentially identical. The benefits for this functional approach I'm advocating that works for either `service` or `factory` is that you should reduce garbage collection by instantiating less objects, it should be the faster implementation by never instantiating, and there is no state maintained.

Ultimately, to answer your question, you weren't misusing `service` or `factory`. Rather, the documentation you quoted appears to expect you to not maintain state within the service directly, since it is a singleton. My recommendation would be to change your code moving forward to behave more like this as you'll probably fit the "angular way" better.